# Can the columns on Fieldbook be rearranged?

Tags: fieldbook

I've just got my invitation to [Fieldbook](http://fieldbook.com) today. I'm playing with it right now and I've created some sheets. I'm trying to change the order of the columns on some sheets but can't seem to do it via the UI. How can I change the column order?

Comment: I've already learned how to change the order of the columns by the OP who requested this question to be migrated here. You have to switch to the list view where there are column headers which you can drag to change the order of the columns. My question is, if it's really off-topic just to ask if something is possible to achieve programmatically. After all I'm not asking about how it's done programmatically. Eventually it turned out to be possible on the UI. I'll be more than happy to delete this question if it's not suitable for Webapps.

Comment: What would a useful answer be? It's either "yes, it's possible" or "no, it's not".  What other value could be added to that? If your question simply asked how to do what you're looking for, that would absolutely be on-topic.

Comment: Can I save the question by formulating it in the way you're suggesting?

Comment: I encourage you to do so, by all means. Since you also seem to have discovered a solution, it'd be awesome if you added an answer as well

Comment: I'll write the answer next week including a few screenshots.

Comment: I've taken a stab at "genericizing" the question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns have a little line on top of them which include an equal sign in them. When you scroll your pointer onto them it morphs into a hand icon.

> - Clicking and holding the hand on one of the columns will start a replacement process of the column.
> - Move the column into its new location. The app displays a blinking line on the left side of the target column.
> - When you release the button (the hand icon) where you want to replace the column, it leaves the relocated column into its new
>     location.